# Finding the equation of an ellipse for modeling a physical system

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, mathematical-modeling

I'm trying to model a physical system in parameter space and I got the following equations:
$$
x=P[a\cos(wt)+b\sin(wt)] 
$$
$$
y=Q\sin(wt)
$$
all constants are known parameters. I'm having extreme difficulty attempting to get this into a form of an ellipse either in
$$(x^2/\alpha^2)+(y^2/\beta^2)=1$$
Any advice?

Comment: are you sure the first formula is correct? Mayve $\cos,\sin$ should be squared?

Answer (score 2):

Yes; you cannot write your curve as $\frac{x^2}{\alpha^2}+\frac{y^2}{\beta^2}=1$, because your ellipse is not parallel to the $x$- and $y$-axes.

To obtain a Cartesian description of your curve, first note that $$\sin{\omega t}=\frac{y}{Q}$$  Thus $$\cos{\omega t}=\frac{\frac{x}{P}-\frac{by}{Q}}{a}$$  Squaring, $$1=\sin^2{(\omega t)}+\cos^2{(\omega t)}=\left(\frac{y}{Q}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\frac{x}{P}-\frac{by}{Q}}{a}\right)^2$$

Comment: Do you have a typo for $\cos  \omega t$?

Comment: yes it should be minus but otherwise that's perfect. Thank you Jacob!